# How to get E Text Editor to upload local copy of project files to server?

Tags: php, e-texteditor

I'm new to E Text Editor.
I have a project saved locally on my computer, that replicates a folder saved on my server. When I use my php IDE (PhpEd) and save a change to the locally saved file, it automatically updates the respective file on my server.

Can I customize E Text Editor to do this also? It would save lots of time!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually have winscp running in the background. It has a nice "keep remote directory up to date" feature. It does require a stable connection to the server otherwise it has a tendency to fail occasionally.